# The Ergodic Theorem and Universal Reachability

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The impetus for Ergodic Theory came from Boltzmann's hypothesis that a particle in an equilibriated system (say, for instance, a gas) would visit each possible state in the level set $H^{-1}(e)$ of the energy as time asymptotically tended toward infinity. Walters has written that the hypothesis as stated was false, and the well-known ergodic theorem due to Brikhoff instead equates temporal averages of paths with spatial averages of the system.

My question is are there any conditions under which Boltzmann's original claim is true? Specifically, Suppose $(X,\mathcal{B},m)$ is a measure space and $T$ is a transformation on $X$. Suppose we call a subset $U$ of the state space *universally reachable* if for every $x \in X$ there is some index $k$ such that $T^k(x) \in U$. Does knowledge of ergodicity help us to draw any conclusions about the existence and number of such sets? Under what conditions are ergodicity and universal reachability equivalent for some given subset of the state space?

Comment: It seems to me that this definition of universally reachable is way too strict, since it asks that every point $x$ eventually enters such subset. Ergodicity will give you information about the orbit of almost every point. The only notion I can think of that relates more with your question is unique ergodicity, which is quite strong. A system that is uniquely ergodic is minimal, then any open set is reached by the orbit of any point.

Comment: @D.J.Obata there's no issue considering some sort of restricted reachability too. For instance, if we suppose only that there is a subset $V$ such that for all $x \in V$ there is an index $k$ such that $T^k(x) \in U$. $U$ itself will trivially be a subset of $V$ so we are obviously interested in cases where $V$ strictly contains $U$.